# Is there way to add video clips to SharePoint Online news post

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, newsfeed, sitepages, sharepoint-news

I want to be able to add video clips to my news post SharePoint Online. Is there was I can do this?

I can see there is YouTube web part but I want to be able to upload my own video and post it so users are able to watch the video when they are viewing the news article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below are the options to add videos to your SharePoint modern pages:

1. [File viewer web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-a-file-viewer-to-a-sharepoint-space-d1373b38-013e-4c6d-bf52-cc8c0582d0d2):

   Upload your video to SharePoint document library & select the video file in file viewer web part configuration settings.
2. [Microsoft Stream web part](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/stream/embed-video-sharepoint):

   Upload videos to Microsoft steam & show the single video or stream channel on pages using stream web part
3. [Embed web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-content-to-your-page-using-the-embed-web-part-721f3b2f-437f-45ef-ac4e-df29dba74de8):

   Upload your video to SharePoint document library OR Microsoft stream & show it on site page using embed web part (`iframe` code).

   Basic `iframe` example:

   ```
   <iframe width="600" height="600" src="https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/work/library/video.mp4"></iframe>
   ```

Comment: Thanks, Ganesh :)